# Problem with WebKit rendering google.com (and a few other sites)

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I'm a noob to Cocoa programming, so please excuse the possible stupidity of this question.

I'm trying to build a web browser using Cocoa/MacRuby but am running into this strange rendering problem - a lot of sites render just fine, but all Google sites and a bunch of other sites (such as the CouchDB website) render with very small fonts.

I tried to mimic Firefox's HTTP request and set headers like so:

`def initialize_request(url)`

```
  url_request = NSMutableURLRequest.requestWithURL(NSURL.URLWithString(url))
  url_request.setValue("ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept-Charset")
  url_request.setValue("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
  url_request.setValue("en-us,en;q=0.5", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept-Language")
  url_request.setValue("gzip,deflate", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept-Encoding")
  url_request.setValue("keep-alive", forHTTPHeaderField:"Connection")
  url_request.setValue("300", forHTTPHeaderField:"Keep-Alive")

  headers = url_request.allHTTPHeaderFields
  NSLog("All headers: #{headers.inspect}")

  url_request

end
```

Full source file is [here](http://github.com/arunthampi/Namaste/blob/f2ad161ddefeb55f0b1ad00cfaeb438dbdbced5b/NamasteDocument.rb)

Any pointers will be helpful, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the font size in your app's WebPreferences and the text-size multiplier on the WebView.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that. Thanks again guys!